# How to re write Office Automation Code

Tags: c#, ms-access, office-interop

[image][image][image]VS 2008 / C# / MS 2007

I have a Saved Import Feature in Access Database which invokes ODBC Connection. Instead of depending on In-built Saved Import feature, i am trying to rewrite the feature in C# which will call ODBC Connection to Import Data to MS Access Database.

I am not able to call the connection string which is saved in the Access Database which calls ODBC Drivers. I keep failing .. !!

```
    Access.Application access1 = new Access.Application();
    try
    {

        string sSalisburyAccessDB = Server.MapPath("App_Data/Database1.mdb");
        access1.OpenCurrentDatabase(sSalisburyAccessDB, true, null);

        // Drop the existing table data

        access1.DoCmd.DeleteObject(Access.AcObjectType.acTable, "plans");

        access1.DoCmd.DeleteObject(Access.AcObjectType.acTable, "price");

        // Run the saved import
        access1.DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport("TestODBC");

        // Close the database
        access1.CloseCurrentDatabase();

        // Quit MS Access
        access1.Quit(Access.AcQuitOption.acQuitSaveAll);

        Response.Write("successful");



    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To me it seems you are using automation in IIS (Server.Mappath... ans Response.Write...) ?

IF this is the case THEN this is NOT supported by MS - see http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2

Reasons are several: starting from security and not ending with the fact that office was never built for such server usage scenario...

I don't understand why you are not just using ODBC from C# instead of MS Access ? Perhaps you could show some more surce code or the exception/error message... ?

**EDIT - after long discussion (see comments):**

IF you need to access the Faircom DB then add a `using System.Data.Odbc;` and try

```
OdbcConnection DbConnection2Salisbury = new OdbcConnection("DSN=Salisbury;DBQ=S:\;CODEPAGE=1252;");

DbConnection2Salisbury.Open();
```

After this you are able to use ADO.NET to query etc. the Faircom DB i.e. with `OdbcCommand` and `OdbcDataReader` etc.

For some information see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.aspx
For sample code see http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/csharp/ado-net-odbc.html

Comment: Okay please explain me how to use the connection string : ODBC;DSN=Salisbury;DBQ=S:\;CODEPAGE=1252;   This is part of my question -How to use, open, close this dsn connection and extract the data !!

Comment: i have been to that website even before i come to stackoverflow, i am here to get the solution !!

Comment: the connection string you provide is not sufficient to answer the question - there must be on that system either a file or system DSN with the name Salisbury - you need to to post what the content/configuration settings for Salisbury are for anyone to help

Comment: Check the ODBC Administrator for settings of Salisbury and post themn then we should be able to solve this

Comment: Can you able to see the screen shot of Access DB. Connection string which i mentioned is generated automatically by Office 2007. If i invoke the saved method ( Saved Connection string ) is actually, i am invoking the Office Automation Method

Comment: Our ODBC Drivers are connected to C-Tree Database. You can view the architect design for establishing ODBC Connection with Ctree database from http://www.faircom.com/ace/ace_api_odbc_t.php

Comment: I understand that - still there must be somewhere a so-called DSN (either file or system) which is then used by the ODBC driver... and the settings of that DSN for Salisbury are needed to help you... even if Office genrates this.

Comment: You don't have to have a DSN in order to access data via ODBC.

Comment: since this is ctree according to their website DSN-less ODBC doesn't have a DSN setting (http://www.faircom.com/doc/ctpodbc/38030.htm)... if the connection has a DSN setting then there must be a DSN (http://www.faircom.com/doc/crystal/22197.htm)... the string shown by OP refers to a DSN called Salisbury which means there is somewhere a DSN - and that is what I am asking about...

Comment: @David, i didnt get your point !! ODBC Driver connection is mentioned on DSN Settings !!

Comment: @Yahia - Your recent comment doesnt seem to be relevant to my posting !! I have mentioned very clearly that we are using ODBC Drivers on MS Access Database which in turn depends on DSN Settings !! DSN Settings are mapped with C-Tree database !!So, if i want to extract data to MS Access database, values are fetched through DSN which pumped into ODBC Drivers to Access DB

Comment: @Yahia, One simple question how to call this connection from C# code and invoke it from Click event or any other event !!

Comment: I undestrand your question... BUT I perhaps did not make myself clear: the connection you show does not contain alle relevant settings, it depends on a DSN called Salisbury... without knowing the settings of Salisbury I don't see a way to give a solution more clear

Comment: @Yahia, In the connection string, you are able to see DSN = Salisbury. Salisbury is a Shared folder in the Linux Server Machine !!

Comment: and what is in the shared folder ?

Comment: folder carries C-Tree Database Tables. C-Tree Database is a very light weight database. It will not be just like one Big Database as what we see in SQL - .mdf / .ldf files !!! Instead they will be located in a folder with file extensions .dat !! Table1.dat, Table2.dat will be located in that folder !!! Folder carries all .dat files which are actually tables !!!

Comment: is the folder mounted with a drive letter at the windows machine ?

Comment: @Yahia - I wish to explain with screen shot, But for some reasons i am not able to include Screenshots in the Add Comment

Comment: @Yahia:  A small correction on my comment !! Salisbury is the name of the ODBC Driver communicating the Linux Server / Shared Folder.  So this driver is mapped to the folder in the Linux Server.

Comment: @Yahia let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2333/discussion-between-chok-and-yahia)

Comment: Okay, i have added new screen shots !! Please have a look on it !! Its about ODBC Driver and it's connection Salisbury !! Also, Please have a look on this website :http://www.faircom.com/ace/ace_api_odbc_t.php

Comment: @yahia, Please give me some time, let me test this code and get back to you !!

Comment: @yahia OdbcConnection DbConnection2Salisbury = new OdbcConnection("DSN=Salisbury;DBQ=S:\;CODEPAGE=1252;");      This line is throwing Syntax Error right next to S:\;  - Semicolon is throwing an error !!!

Comment: By writting "SN=Salisbury" - I am able to Open the ODBC Connection !! i.e) I am able to succeed on very first step ..!!!       OdbcConnection DbConnection = new OdbcConnection("DSN=Salisbury");
            DbConnection.Open();

            OdbcCommand DbCommand = DbConnection.CreateCommand();
            DbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Price";
            OdbcDataReader DbReader = DbCommand.ExecuteReader();



            DbReader.Close();
            DbCommand.Dispose();
            DbConnection.Close();

Comment: @Yahia - Above piece of code, helps me to open and close the DSN Connection through C# code.  Now, i have to search for more help to extract or read the tables !! Above piece of code is just opening and closing .. but we dont know how to read the table or export the table to SQL database !! Now, i am trying to find out the way to either to export the tables from there to MS Access or SQL ... !!

Comment: I added S:\ Folder and files which is located, you can see .dat files ..!! Those are C-Tree tables

Comment: try calling `GetSchema()` on the connection... it returns a DataTable with Schema information for the tables of the ODBC/DSN connection

Comment: DbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Price"; OdbcDataReader DbReader = DbCommand.ExecuteReader(); DbReader.GetSchemaTable();      Get Schema syntax is not able to read Price Table

Comment: @yahia, if you closely watch MS Access Database Screenshot which i posted on the Comment. You can notice that i am saving the Export /Import function in Access database as SalisburyODBC. If i need to import the Tables back to same Access database, all i need to do is just run the saved function !!  We are trying to get the source code of the Saved Function which is written some where on VBA Macro inside the Access Application

Comment: I understand that but since you are going for an implementation without automation you will have to implement that part in code

Comment: We need that part of code .. which we can re-write it on C# !! That part exports .dat tables from C-Tree database to Access Database !! Atleast, i need to write that part to export Tables to Access Database

Comment: @yahia, if you want to visualize the whole process on my computer, i can arrange that through remote viewer !! this is very important milestone for our project !! i request for your help !!

Comment: @yahia - can I remind you that touting for work is frowned upon on all the Stack Exchange sites. Contact each other privately. Thanks.

Comment: @Kev, i'm sorry !! After a long exchange of comments and kept open this discussion for a while, i still have not find solution for my posting !! I approached for remote viewer option only after discussing this issue for more than 2 weeks !!  I shared the screenshots, sample codes and coordinated with experts. But still we are not able  to find the solution for our issue !! So, i thought there could be a possible to find the solution on visualize the scenario !!

Comment: @chok and yahia - ok, just wanted to make sure you understood :) now...you both have enough rep to take this discussion over to a chat room, please can you do that. We get flags for more than 20 comments added to a post. Thanks.

Comment: @Kev -  I am willing to coordinate and share any details required by experts !! I am desperately in need of finding solution for our issue which i posted over here !!

Comment: @Kev, will you please allow expert to visualize the flow of the application through remote viewing option !! We haven't found solution yet !! Question is kept open !

Comment: @Kev, i havent received any solution for my posting. How to revoke my 50 points ??

Comment: @chok - bounties are non-refundable. Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work